# How to schedule two separate crontabs

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks, cron, cron-task

It supposed to be simple, but I must be missing something.

`deletelogs` file:

```
0 11 * * 6 ./scripts/deletelogs.sh
```

`backupstuff` file:

```
0 23 * * * ./scripts/backupstuff.sh
```

`crontab -l` shows the `deletelogs` job

If I do `crontab backupstuff`, then `crontab -l` shows the `backupstuff` job.

How can I schedule both, Why can't I list both with `crontab -l`?

Comment: It was very difficult to tell from your question what the exact contents of the files was and what commands you were executing. I've edited your question to try to make it clearer. Please check that it still reflects what you're asking.

Comment: You're welcome -- and call me Ford. 8-)} http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Prefect_(character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `crontab` file can read a set of entries from a file named on its command line:

```
crontab filename
```

or from standard input:

```
echo ... | crontab
```

Both commands replace the entire crontab.

To combine two input files:

```
cat file1 file2 | crontab
```

To add the contents of a file to an existing crontab:

```
( crontab -l ; cat file ) | crontab
```

Personally, I keep my entire crontab in a single file, installed with a simple `crontab filename`; I keep that file under a source control system so I can restore it if I make a mistake. But if you have a need to split it into multiple files, you can do that.